# Add track to iTunes playlist using JXA

Tags: macos, automation, itunes, javascript-automation

I'm trying to build a simple JavaScript for Automation script to add the currently playing track in iTunes to a particular playlist.

I have the playlist name stored as a string, `var playlist`.

The JXA Library add method says the following:

> add method : add one or more files to a playlist
>
> > add list of file : the file(s) to add
> >
> > > [to: location specifier] : the location of the added file(s)
> > >
> > > → Track : reference to added track(s)

What I can't figure out is what to put for the `[to: location specifier]` part to specify a playlist.

I tried:

```
playlist = 'Queue'
iTunes = Application('iTunes')
iTunes.add(iTunes.currentTrack, {to: iTunes.playlists[playlist]})
```

But I get "Error -1708: Message not understood."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add` doesn't do what you want here (`add` is used primarily for importing files outside of iTunes into the application, that's what the location specifier refers to).

You want to use the `duplicate` method on the track you want to "duplicate", copying it "to" the destination playlist. This code snippet works for me:

```
var iTunes = Application('iTunes');
var playlist = iTunes.playlists['Queue'];
iTunes.currentTrack().duplicate({to:playlist});
```